# C# -> code to look at code

Tags: c#

Is there a good way to, say, print a list of all the methods in my project or file?

And from there, list of classes or variables, etc.

Comment: Check out Red Gate Reflector.

Comment: You can use various things in the reflection namespace to query assemblies for what classes they contain, what methods they have, etc.

Comment: ... Or ILSpy, JustDecompile, DotPeek (these ones are actually free).

Comment: Like some sort of documentation generator?  Do you comment your code with /// ?

Comment: You should add some context to your question. Are you trying to analyze your program while it is running ? Or analyzing the contents of a project in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the System.Reflection namespace. You'll have to play around with the BindingFlags enumeration to get exactly what you want, but here's a quick example program:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ReflectionExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type[] types = typeof (MyClass).Assembly.GetTypes();

            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type.Name);

                MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMembers(
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public
                    | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

                foreach (MemberInfo memberInfo in members)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + memberInfo.Name);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class MyClass
        {
            public int Bar { get; set; }

            public void AMethod()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("foo");
            }

            public void BMethod()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("foo");
            }

            public void CMethod()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("foo");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could /// document everything in your project and then turn on the XML documentation output in your project settings. I guess it depends on what you need this list for.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're trying to do. If you're looking to analyze your .NET executable, you can use one of the free decompilation tools available ([dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) or even [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)).

However, if you're looking for this information at runtime, that is, you want for example to print all the types and methods executing in your application, you can either use Reflection (here's a [good tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET) on CodeProject), or use an AOP solution, like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com), to print the names of all executing methods (see the [Tracing example](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection to list classes, methods, properties.

Here
[Reflection](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/12/reflection-in-c-list-of-class-name.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about print capabilities, but have you looked at [.Net Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

With reflection you can find any meta data about functions, classes etc.
C# has very good support for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string dllPathName = @"dllPath\dllFileName";
        string outputFilePathName = @"outputPath\outputFileName";
        System.Reflection.Assembly fileNetAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPathName);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Type cls in fileNetAssembly.GetTypes())
        {
            //only printing non interfaces that are abstract, public or sealed
            sb.Append(!cls.IsInterface ? (cls.IsAbstract ? string.Format("Class: {0} is Abstract.{1}", cls.Name, System.Environment.NewLine) :
                                            cls.IsPublic ? string.Format("Class: {0} is Public.{1}", cls.Name, System.Environment.NewLine) :
                                            cls.IsSealed ? string.Format("Class: {0} is Sealed.{1}", cls.Name, System.Environment.NewLine) :
                                            string.Empty) : 
                                        string.Empty);

            if (!cls.IsInterface && (cls.IsAbstract || cls.IsPublic || cls.IsSealed))
            {
                //printing all methods within the class
                foreach (System.Reflection.MemberInfo method in cls.GetMethods())
                {
                    sb.Append("\t- ");
                    sb.Append(method.Name);
                    sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }

        //output the file
        File.WriteAllText(outputFilePathName, sb.ToString());
```